# Validate Oracle dmp

Tags: oracle, backup, export, validation, dump

I have a Oracle backup done with EXP utility.

How can I validate it? 
Is there any command/tool to validate the backup archive?

Thank you!

Comment: Just for the record, EXP is not really a backup tool, it's ... well, it's an *export* tool.

Comment: Not sure where I heard it, but: "if you haven't done a test restore, you haven't done a backup"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run:

```
imp file=xxx.dmp show=Y full=y userid=user@db
```

This will list the contents of the export file without actually doing any actual import operations. I would assume that if the import utility could make sense of the export file, then it's a valid export file.

EDIT:

"Validate" is a vague term. I have made the assumption that what you want is a tool to make sure the file can be imported at some point in the future. This should do that. If you're looking for something more, like a sanity or consistency check on the actual data, I know of nothing other than to do the export with CONSISTENT=Y, which will give you a read-consistent view of the data as of the time the export started.

Comment: I agree that "validate" is too vague.  What is your business environment like, how important is this backup?  In many companies a DBA would be fired if the backups were lost or didn't work.  For true peace of mind, and better CYA, you need to perform the full import on another database (with the same or very similar configuration) and make sure it works correctly.